# Does Excel have a keyboard shortcut to find contents of selected cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

99.9% of the time I'm searching in Excel spreadsheets the same way,

- within sheet
- by row
- look in: values
- find next

Can select a cell, and then find next cell containing that content with a quick keyboard shortcut? (the text editing software Vim has a similar shortcut to *find word under cursor* [shift] + 8)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a macro that will find the next cell with the same value as the `Active Cell`, and then assign a keyboard short cut to the macro.

See below for an example macro:

```
Sub SetValue()

findval = ActiveCell.Value

    Cells.Find(What:=findval, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

End Sub
```

It is not case sensitive.

Change :

```
MatchCase:= _ False
```

To `True` if you wish it to be case sensitive.